# Is it possible to do indent only with css, image inside

Tags: css, indentation

[image: Indent like this]

Is it possible to do this only with CSS?
I thought about it a long time but nothing comes to my mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but only if your background has a solid color:

```
div {
    width: 310px;
    height: 41px;
    background: gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
div:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
    bottom: -30px;
}
```

Also check the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/ThZrf/).

EDIT: added the inner shadow: http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/ThZrf/1/

Comment: Your welcome! If the answer suits you, please mark it as 'solution' by hitting the 'v'-mark on the left of it.

Comment: I know page says I have to wait for 2 minutes

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can create a relatively positioned div and give it a border-radius of a high number (you'll have to experiment to find at what point it becomes a circle) specify a width and height for it, set it's z-index to being higher than the thing it is sitting on top of and position it in the bottom corner. Something like

```
#circle{
    border-radius: 300px;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 40px;
    width:40px;
    left: 350px;
    top: 20px;
    background-colour:white;
}
```

These are only sample values. You'll need your own to do this correctly. If you wanted to get even more fancy I think you can specify which corners to apply the radius to. So you could (I think) create that exact shape in CSS rather than a circle which my method would do (but you position the circle to cut out just the corner).

**EDIT: As pointed out, if you want a shadow, you can play about with the css box-shadow attribute(note this is not supported below IE9).**

Comment: You could do this, but you wouldn't get the inner shadow as shown in his image at the bottom right.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo I've not used it but I'm guessing box-shadow could be used here?

Comment: Michael - the most important is the shape

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your particular use case, you might consider this technique by Lea Verou:
http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/